# Tiny white spot continuously appearing on the Laptop screen

Tags: computer-hardware

As I mentioned in the title, I am continously seeing this white spot, which as per my assumption, based on some Googling, is a pixel turned on, on the Laptop screen.

But the thing is, if I visit any dark page or website, it doesn't show the spot at the same position but in the other cases it does ?

Is this surely a hardware-only issue(which can be fixed by repairs or replacement only) or just a hardware glitch, which will go away, once I reboot the system ? I am currently doing office work, so can't reboot for few hours.

How do I remove that white spot ? Please advise with detailed understanding and information...

Comment: Check ith the manufacturer - there may be a screen recall. But that is not our purpose.

Comment: I suggest including the picture of the issue. Also some information about laptop might be helpful, make, model etc. Also have checked with your company IT department.

Comment: You most likely won't be able to remove the white spot from the screen. I bought a new laptop computer 9 years & it had a small white (bright) spot on the screen when I first got the computer. With near daily usage over the past 9 years the bright spot is still there, but slightly larger. It's most likely a manufacturing fault. If your computer/screen is still under warranty you might be able to get it replaced.

Answer (score 1):

This is aka "hot pixel". Usually it is a failure of hardware in the screen itself and irreparable. It's not uncommon but there are ways to attempt correction with a hot cloth while the screen is switched off then booted up. 30-40% have it may work. To heat the cloth is a work of art: boil it in water, wring it out and place in a very thin watertight bag and apply it to the area of the affected screen.

Be warned, do this at your own peril. I have no responsibility for any damage it may cause.

Comment: OK, to be honest, have you ever tried this way? If yes , did it work or fail? @Rhodie

Comment: Yes, I had several and it worked for most of them

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you find Dead Pixel Tester for Windows. DPT.exe and define a square on the screen for exercising all the pixels in that square.  Many zones can be flashed with colors just like soft errors in flash memory, and may recover.

An LCD also works by a stored charge and transistor amplifier. if only a trapped charge is at fault , it is dynamic. if not it’s a dead transistor stick on or off.   Worked for me 8 yrs ago when this was a problem.  it may take hours to fix if possible and although a trapped charge is somewhat like degaussing a CRT except localized.

DPT is also excellent for Monitor calibration for TV or flat screen with many test patterns.